# How does posting query parameters in CodeIgniter work?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this format on links:

```
blah/link/11
```

where blah is the controller and link is a function inside it. But now I want to send a number in the querystring. In normal non-MVC way I would have done like this:

```
page.php?id=11
```

So what should I do for getting the eleven in my link function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Blah extends Controller {

    function link( $id ) {
        // $id == 11
    }

}
```

reachable via URL `blah/link/11`

Answer (score 2):

There may be other ways to go about this, but it looks like CodeIgniter has a [URI Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) that will allow you to retrieve specific segments of your URI.  So something like

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3); //from a controller, I assume
```

should get you what you want.

It also [looks like](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri) CodeIgniter will take additional URI parameters and pass them through as parameters to your action function.

```
#http://example.com/index.php/products/shoes/sandals/123
class Products extends Controller {

    function shoes($sandals, $id)
    {
        echo $sandals;
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I never realized he was working inside another framework. I thought he was building his own. :) I think the title was changed.